# how to merge specific columns in a file?

Tags: linux, shell, merge, command

I have a txt file looks like below.

```
bt18    56357609    56363423    color=40,   0,  255,    0.8
bt15    29887448    29918570    color=10,   200,    40, 0.8
```

Columns are separated by tab.
The problem is the last 4 columns should be one like below.

```
bt18    56357609    56363423    color=40,0,255,0.8
bt15    29887448    29918570    color=10,200,40,0.8
```

I know how to remove/change separators with command but don't know how to do it to specific columns.

Please, help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} { print $1, $2, $3, $4 $5 $6 $7 }' infile > outfile
```

Comment: Thank you! What does `BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}` do in your command?

Comment: `FS` is the input field separator, `OFS` is the output field separator. So that says that the fields are separated by a tab.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4$5$6$7 }'  infile > outfile
```